# Both (funcall (lambda and (lambda worked

Tags: elisp

I am reading [Simple-Lambda](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Simple-Lambda.html#Simple-Lambda) in elisp docs with an example

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :session sicp :lexical t
     (funcall (lambda (a b c) (+ a b c))
              1 (* 2 3) (- 5 4))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 8
```

the below works as well

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :session sicp :lexical t
((lambda (a b c) (+ a b c))
 1 (* 2 3) (- 5 4))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 8
```

This confused me, elisp is lisp-2 style, so when evaluate `(lambda (a b c) (+ a b c))`, the interpreter will look into the block's cell for definition object, and thus the doc's demonstration make sense to invoke `funcall`

```
     (funcall (lambda (a b c) (+ a b c))
              1 (* 2 3) (- 5 4))
```

Nonetheless, it works without funcall?

```
((lambda (a b c) (+ a b c))
 1 (* 2 3) (- 5 4))
```

Additionally, lambda is not of self-evaluating forms

> It is common to write numbers, characters, strings, and even vectors
>   in Lisp code, taking advantage of the fact that they self-evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

Elisp has a special case for `lambda` forms being called directly.

```
((lambda ...) ...)
```

As you've noted, that approach doesn't work in more general cases for other function-returning forms.  It is also deprecated for this case where it does work, so it's best not to use it at all.

This syntax is covered briefly in `(elisp)Function Indirection`:

> the following example calls a function without any
>   symbol function indirection, because the first element is an anonymous
>   Lisp function, not a symbol.
>
> ```
> ((lambda (arg) (erste arg))
>  '(1 2 3))
>      ⇒ 1
> ```
>
> Executing the function itself evaluates its body; this does involve
>   symbol function indirection when calling ‘erste’.
>
> This form is rarely used and is now deprecated.  Instead, you should
>   write it as:
>
> ```
> (funcall (lambda (arg) (erste arg))
>          '(1 2 3))
> ```
>
> or just
>
> ```
> (let ((arg '(1 2 3))) (erste arg))
> ```